# Flask: send_from_directory and also refresh the page

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I am using send_from_directory in flask which will allow a user to download a certain file. What I want to achieve is that the page refreshes after the file is downloaded, but I'm unsure how I can achieve this with flask (if at all possible). Currently my code looks like this:

```
if report:
            location = Document_Generator(report).file_location

            return send_from_directory(location[0],
                               location[1], as_attachment=True)
```

So my question is : How can I refresh the page (return a normal response with a template) as well as allowing the user to download the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP doesn't let you do what you want to do (200 + 300).  You *can* do it at the client level however using `_target` + JavaScript (or just JavaScript).

```
<a href="/path/to/download/file" target="downloadIframe">Download file</a>
<iframe id="downloadIframe"></iframe>
```

Combined with some JavaScript:

```
var slice = Array.prototype.slice;

var links = document.querySelectorAll("[target='downloadIframe']"),
    iframe = document.getElementById("downloadIframe");
slice.call(links).forEach(function(link) {
    link.addEventListener("click", reloadPageOnIframeLoad);
});

function reloadPageOnIframeLoad() {
    // Reset this for each click on a download link
    // rather than adding another event listener each time.
    iframe.onload = function() { window.location.reload(); };
}
```