# How to delete file after user download with bottle framework...?

Tags: python, python-2.7, bottle, yocto

I use python with bottle framework. When the user clicks a button, the server should generate file and let the user download it. When the user downloads it completely, the server should delete this file.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried that or you want us write code for you?

Comment: I found some information,look like should use hooks plugin ...?
But, I can't understand how to use it...

Comment: Well, here is Stack Overflow. So I think you should Google your question first. And try to write some code. If your run your code and got an error, then you can ask here.

Comment: I tried google my question first, but lots of result about flask framework...

Comment: Hmm...you're right. But I think you still doesn't ask some question like this...Let me search about this again.

Comment: So your problem is that you can't know the browser has finished downloaded the file or the file is downloading right? I've just see [the tutorial](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html) and I can't find any helpful things.

Comment: OK... thanks for your response. I will apply for delete this question.

Comment: I think you can keep this question, however this is a difficult question :)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I don't know how to do function after browser request.

Comment: However I can't solve this, so good luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found the way by [this page (flask solution)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24613980/4192373) and [this page(hooks plugin)](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/recipes.html#using-the-hooks-plugin) and [this page(Forced Download)](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#static-files).

this is my solution:

> **put hook "after_request" function into route function**

part of my code:

download page templete (only one button):

```
<form id="export" calss="etable" method="POST" action="/download">
    <input type="submit" name="export" value="export">  
</form>
```

download page

```
@route('/download')
def download():
    output = template('download',template_lookup=['./views'])       
    return output
```

click button(generate file and redirect to download)

```
@route('/download',method = 'POST')
def downloadPost():
    zipname = zipFolder('./temp') #create files
    if zipname is not None:
        return redirect('/download/'+zipname)
    else:
        abort(500,'error.')
```

Forced Download function (**put hook in this part.**)

```
@route('/download/<filename:path>')
def download_file(filename):
    @hook('after_request')
    def delFiles():
        del('./temp/',filename) #delete file function       
    return static_file(filename, root='./temp/', download=filename)
```