# Flask unable to delete file after send_file()

Tags: python, api, flask

```
@app.route("/test")
def test_func():
    @after_this_request
    def delete_file(response):
        os.remove('test.txt')
        return response
        
    return send_file('test.txt')
```

I have test.txt in the same directory as my code. All I wanna do is delete the file I send, but when I access this GET method, I run into the following error:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'test.txt' 127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2021 19:47:53] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

thank you in advance

Comment: You might consider using [celery](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/celery/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that `@after_this_request` causes `delete_file()` to be passed in the "proposed" response object produced by `test_func()`.  `@after_this_request` gives `delete_file()` the opportunity to modify the response before it is sent.

So, your `os.remove('test.txt')` is actually being called before `send_file()` has completed.

You can see this in [the help](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.after_this_request) for `@after_this_request`.  It says "The function is passed the response object and has to return the same or a new one."  So you can see from that the code will be run before the response is actually returned.

For a solution, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24612366/delete-an-uploaded-file-after-downloading-it-from-flask).